# Accessing Controller Scope from child Directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, directive, isolate-scope

I want to access a controller scope without using $parent. From everything I read, I thought I could just pass it into the isolate scope as follows:

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>
      {{message}}
    </h1>
    <mydir></mydir>
```

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.message = "Hello World";
})

.directive('mydir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      message: "=",
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.goodbye = function(){
        $scope.message = "Goodbye World";
      }
    },
    template: "<button ng-click='goodbye()'>Say Goodbye</button>"
  }
})
```

However, I can't get the directive to update the scope's `message` property. [Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IxPpQtWuLFojC7Rk1kMG?p=info).

Comment: Controllers have specific behavior for a page/partial and directives are generic so it should be allow reuse. A directive can't depends on a controller scope. You have to passed as parameter as suggests Pankaj Parkar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the isolated scope value can passed using `attribute`, then you need to have `message` attribute on directive element which will have the scope variable name.

```
<mydir message="message"></mydir>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/STAEvCeQjpBEGdwYnu1N?p=preview)